# Average the values of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, average

I have the following list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has a `"Point"` and a `"Value"` and goes from `1` to `10`, for each **series** of points.

```
My_list = [{"Point": 1, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 2, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 3, "Value": 40}, \
{"Point": 4, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 5, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 6, "Value": 40}, \
{"Point": 7, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 8, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 9, "Value": 0},{"Point": 10, "Value": 250},\
    {"Point": 1, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 2, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 3, "Value": 40}, \
{"Point": 4, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 5, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 6, "Value": 40}, \
{"Point": 7, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 8, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 9, "Value": 0},{"Point": 10, "Value": 250},\
    {"Point": 1, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 2, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 3, "Value": 40}, \
{"Point": 4, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 5, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 6, "Value": 40}, \
{"Point": 7, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 8, "Value": 40}, {"Point": 9, "Value": 0},{"Point": 10, "Value": 250}]
```

I would like to find the average `'Value'` for every 2 `'Point'`, without messing with the `'Value'` of the next **series**. I have done the following.

```
every2 = []
counter = 2
temp = []
for point in My_list:
    if counter > 0:
        temp.append(point["Value"])
    else:
        p = point
        p["Value"] = sum(temp)/len(temp)
        every2.append(point)
        # reset the counter after every 2 point
        counter = 2
        temp = []
        # temp.append(point["Value"])
    counter -= 1

print(every2)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
[{'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 9, 'Value': 40.0},  
 {'Point': 1, 'Value': 250.0}, {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},  
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 1, 'Value': 250.0}, {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},  
{'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 9, 'Value': 40.0}]
```

However I am missing the first `'Point'`, as the `'Point'` of the first series starts from 3 instead of 1 and as a consequence the `'Point'` 9 has a value of 40 instead of 125.

So what I want should look like this:

```
[{'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},   
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0}, {'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},  
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0}, {'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},  
{'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0}, {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0}]
```

Comment: What if there's an odd number of dictionaries?

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I have done some preprocessing and all the series of dicts in My_list have an even number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `step` argument to `range()` that will allow you to iterate over the list in steps of 2. Then, get both elements you want to use, create a new element using the values, and append that to your result list.

```
result_list = []

n_step = 2           # chunk size is 2

for i in range(0, len(My_list), n_step):
    # Get all elements in this chunk
    elems = My_list[i:i+n_step] 

    # Find the average of the Value key in elems
    avg = sum(item['Value'] for item in elems) / len(elems) 

    # Point key from the first element; Value key from average
    new_item = {"Point": elems[0]["Point"], "Value": avg}
    result_list.append(new_item)
```

Which gives:

```
[{'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0},
 {'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0},
 {'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension

```
res = [{**data[n], **{'Value': sum(v['Value']/2 for v in data[n: n+2])}} for n in range(0, len(data), 2)]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0},
 {'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0},
 {'Point': 1, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 3, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 5, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 7, 'Value': 40.0},
 {'Point': 9, 'Value': 125.0}]
```

For python 3.9+

```
[data[n] | {'Value': sum(v['Value']/2 for v in data[n: n+2])} for n in range(0, len(data), 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that's using `zip` to "parallel loop" over `My_list` with an offset:

```
result = [
    {"Point": p1["Point"], "Value": (p1["Value"] + p2["Value"]) / 2}
    for p1, p2 in zip(My_list[::2], My_list[1::2])
]
```

Requirement is that all the series have even length.